# an integer or string of size 1 is required exception

Tags: android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I was trying a sketch program found online that connects wirelessly to my Raspberry pi using HttpURLConnection.. it's catching the exception "an integer or string of size 1 is required" and i dunno where's the error yet. The program basically sends a character or number when the user hits a button on UI to the webserver running on Raspberry pi. here's a part of the send command:

```java
private void sendCommand(String command) {
    final String cmd = command;

    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {

        private String resp;

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                resp = Sender.getStringResponseFromGetRequest(
                        "http://192.168.1.111:8888/" + cmd);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                resp = e.getMessage();
            }
            return null;
        }

    };
}
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            if(!resp.equals("OK")){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, resp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    };

    task.execute();
}
```

}

and here's the getStringResponse.. Method:

```java
public static String getStringResponseFromGetRequest(String requestUrl)
        throws IOException {
    URL url1;
    URLConnection urlConnection;
    DataInputStream inStream;

    url1 = new URL(requestUrl);
    urlConnection = url1.openConnection();
    ((HttpURLConnection) urlConnection).setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

    inStream = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

    return inStream.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Is this the whole code of the AsyncTask? Your throwing the respone away and return null. BTW you should close open connections...

Comment: thx for ur response. it wasn't the full code but i've edited the post and added the rest of it. I'm not familiar with android programming alot but as you said the connection needs to be closed, wonder how it worked with the original programmer (i mentioned above that i didn't write it :) ) 
BTW im just curious how can i send a character to a specific url.. is the method above right?